# navigator.getUserMedia is not a function using WebRTC

Tags: node.js, websocket, webrtc, simplewebrtc

I try to build a video group confference stream with some people and i use WebRTC (From here: https://github.com/anoek/webrtc-group-chat-example) and as server i use VPS Centos 7 with node js installed and when i try to start my webrtc server, in the browser i see this error on accessing the ip with port

This error:

```
(index):260 Uncaught TypeError: navigator.getUserMedia is not a function
    at setup_local_media ((index):260)
    at Socket.<anonymous> ((index):50)
    at Socket.Emitter.emit (socket.io-1.4.5.js:3)
    at Socket.emit (socket.io-1.4.5.js:3)
    at Socket.onconnect (socket.io-1.4.5.js:3)
    at Socket.onpacket (socket.io-1.4.5.js:3)
    at Manager.<anonymous> (socket.io-1.4.5.js:3)
    at Manager.Emitter.emit (socket.io-1.4.5.js:3)
    at Manager.ondecoded (socket.io-1.4.5.js:2)
    at Decoder.<anonymous> (socket.io-1.4.5.js:3)
```

JS code:

```
 /*************/
    /*** SETUP ***/
    /*************/
   var express = require('express');
   var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
   var cors = require('cors')
   var main = express()
   main.use(cors())
   var server = main.listen(8000);
   var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

    main.get('/', function(req, res){ res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client.html'); });
    /*************************/
    /*** INTERESTING STUFF ***/
    /*************************/
    var channels = {};
    var sockets = {};

    /**
     * Users will connect to the signaling server, after which they'll issue a "join"
     * to join a particular channel. The signaling server keeps track of all sockets
     * who are in a channel, and on join will send out 'addPeer' events to each pair
     * of users in a channel. When clients receive the 'addPeer' even they'll begin
     * setting up an RTCPeerConnection with one another. During this process they'll
     * need to relay ICECandidate information to one another, as well as SessionDescription
     * information. After all of that happens, they'll finally be able to complete
     * the peer connection and will be streaming audio/video between eachother.
     */
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.channels = {};
        sockets[socket.id] = socket;

        console.log("["+ socket.id + "] connection accepted");
        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            for (var channel in socket.channels) {
                part(channel);
            }
            console.log("["+ socket.id + "] disconnected");
            delete sockets[socket.id];
        });


        socket.on('join', function (config) {
            console.log("["+ socket.id + "] join ", config);
            var channel = config.channel;
            var userdata = config.userdata;

            if (channel in socket.channels) {
                console.log("["+ socket.id + "] ERROR: already joined ", channel);
                return;
            }

            if (!(channel in channels)) {
                channels[channel] = {};
            }

            for (id in channels[channel]) {
                channels[channel][id].emit('addPeer', {'peer_id': socket.id, 'should_create_offer': false});
                socket.emit('addPeer', {'peer_id': id, 'should_create_offer': true});
            }

            channels[channel][socket.id] = socket;
            socket.channels[channel] = channel;
        });

        function part(channel) {
            console.log("["+ socket.id + "] part ");

            if (!(channel in socket.channels)) {
                console.log("["+ socket.id + "] ERROR: not in ", channel);
                return;
            }

            delete socket.channels[channel];
            delete channels[channel][socket.id];

            for (id in channels[channel]) {
                channels[channel][id].emit('removePeer', {'peer_id': socket.id});
                socket.emit('removePeer', {'peer_id': id});
            }
        }
        socket.on('part', part);

        socket.on('relayICECandidate', function(config) {
            var peer_id = config.peer_id;
            var ice_candidate = config.ice_candidate;
            console.log("["+ socket.id + "] relaying ICE candidate to [" + peer_id + "] ", ice_candidate);

            if (peer_id in sockets) {
                sockets[peer_id].emit('iceCandidate', {'peer_id': socket.id, 'ice_candidate': ice_candidate});
            }
        });

        socket.on('relaySessionDescription', function(config) {
            var peer_id = config.peer_id;
            var session_description = config.session_description;
            console.log("["+ socket.id + "] relaying session description to [" + peer_id + "] ", session_description);

            if (peer_id in sockets) {
                sockets[peer_id].emit('sessionDescription', {'peer_id': socket.id, 'session_description': session_description});
            }
        });
    });
```

Html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- This adapter.js file de-prefixes the webkit* and moz* prefixed RTC
             methods. When RTC becomes a more solid standard, this adapter should no
             longer be necessary. -->
        <!-- <script src="https://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/js/base/adapter.js"></script> -->
        <style>
            html, body { 
                background-color: #333; 
            }
            video {
                width:  320px;
                height:  240px;
                border:  1px solid black;
            }
        </style>

        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
        <script>
            /** CONFIG **/
            var SIGNALING_SERVER = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
            var USE_AUDIO = true;
            var USE_VIDEO = true;
            var DEFAULT_CHANNEL = 'some-global-channel-name';
            var MUTE_AUDIO_BY_DEFAULT = false;

            /** You should probably use a different stun server doing commercial stuff **/
            /** Also see: https://gist.github.com/zziuni/3741933 **/
            var ICE_SERVERS = [
                {url:"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}
            ];
        </script>


        <script>
            var signaling_socket = null;   /* our socket.io connection to our webserver */
            var local_media_stream = null; /* our own microphone / webcam */
            var peers = {};                /* keep track of our peer connections, indexed by peer_id (aka socket.io id) */
            var peer_media_elements = {};  /* keep track of our <video>/<audio> tags, indexed by peer_id */

            function init() {
                console.log("Connecting to signaling server");
                signaling_socket = io(SIGNALING_SERVER);
                signaling_socket = io();

                signaling_socket.on('connect', function() {
                    console.log("Connected to signaling server");
                    setup_local_media(function() {
                        /* once the user has given us access to their
                         * microphone/camcorder, join the channel and start peering up */
                        join_chat_channel(DEFAULT_CHANNEL, {'whatever-you-want-here': 'stuff'});
                    });
                });
                signaling_socket.on('disconnect', function() {
                    console.log("Disconnected from signaling server");
                    /* Tear down all of our peer connections and remove all the
                     * media divs when we disconnect */
                    for (peer_id in peer_media_elements) {
                        peer_media_elements[peer_id].remove();
                    }
                    for (peer_id in peers) {
                        peers[peer_id].close();
                    }

                    peers = {};
                    peer_media_elements = {};
                });
                function join_chat_channel(channel, userdata) {
                    signaling_socket.emit('join', {"channel": channel, "userdata": userdata});
                }
                function part_chat_channel(channel) {
                    signaling_socket.emit('part', channel);
                }


                /** 
                * When we join a group, our signaling server will send out 'addPeer' events to each pair
                * of users in the group (creating a fully-connected graph of users, ie if there are 6 people
                * in the channel you will connect directly to the other 5, so there will be a total of 15 
                * connections in the network). 
                */
                signaling_socket.on('addPeer', function(config) {
                    console.log('Signaling server said to add peer:', config);
                    var peer_id = config.peer_id;
                    if (peer_id in peers) {
                        /* This could happen if the user joins multiple channels where the other peer is also in. */
                        console.log("Already connected to peer ", peer_id);
                        return;
                    }
                    var peer_connection = new RTCPeerConnection(
                        {"iceServers": ICE_SERVERS},
                        {"optional": [{"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement": true}]} /* this will no longer be needed by chrome
                                                                        * eventually (supposedly), but is necessary 
                                                                        * for now to get firefox to talk to chrome */
                    );
                    peers[peer_id] = peer_connection;

                    peer_connection.onicecandidate = function(event) {
                        if (event.candidate) {
                            signaling_socket.emit('relayICECandidate', {
                                'peer_id': peer_id, 
                                'ice_candidate': {
                                    'sdpMLineIndex': event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                                    'candidate': event.candidate.candidate
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    peer_connection.onaddstream = function(event) {
                        console.log("onAddStream", event);
                        var remote_media = USE_VIDEO ? $("<video>") : $("<audio>");
                        remote_media.attr("autoplay", "autoplay");
                        if (MUTE_AUDIO_BY_DEFAULT) {
                            remote_media.attr("muted", "true");
                        }
                        remote_media.attr("controls", "");
                        peer_media_elements[peer_id] = remote_media;
                        $('body').append(remote_media);
                        attachMediaStream(remote_media[0], event.stream);
                    }

                    /* Add our local stream */
                    peer_connection.addStream(local_media_stream);

                    /* Only one side of the peer connection should create the
                     * offer, the signaling server picks one to be the offerer. 
                     * The other user will get a 'sessionDescription' event and will
                     * create an offer, then send back an answer 'sessionDescription' to us
                     */
                    if (config.should_create_offer) {
                        console.log("Creating RTC offer to ", peer_id);
                        peer_connection.createOffer(
                            function (local_description) { 
                                console.log("Local offer description is: ", local_description);
                                peer_connection.setLocalDescription(local_description,
                                    function() { 
                                        signaling_socket.emit('relaySessionDescription', 
                                            {'peer_id': peer_id, 'session_description': local_description});
                                        console.log("Offer setLocalDescription succeeded"); 
                                    },
                                    function() { Alert("Offer setLocalDescription failed!"); }
                                );
                            },
                            function (error) {
                                console.log("Error sending offer: ", error);
                            });
                    }
                });


                /** 
                 * Peers exchange session descriptions which contains information
                 * about their audio / video settings and that sort of stuff. First
                 * the 'offerer' sends a description to the 'answerer' (with type
                 * "offer"), then the answerer sends one back (with type "answer").  
                 */
                signaling_socket.on('sessionDescription', function(config) {
                    console.log('Remote description received: ', config);
                    var peer_id = config.peer_id;
                    var peer = peers[peer_id];
                    var remote_description = config.session_description;
                    console.log(config.session_description);

                    var desc = new RTCSessionDescription(remote_description);
                    var stuff = peer.setRemoteDescription(desc, 
                        function() {
                            console.log("setRemoteDescription succeeded");
                            if (remote_description.type == "offer") {
                                console.log("Creating answer");
                                peer.createAnswer(
                                    function(local_description) {
                                        console.log("Answer description is: ", local_description);
                                        peer.setLocalDescription(local_description,
                                            function() { 
                                                signaling_socket.emit('relaySessionDescription', 
                                                    {'peer_id': peer_id, 'session_description': local_description});
                                                console.log("Answer setLocalDescription succeeded");
                                            },
                                            function() { Alert("Answer setLocalDescription failed!"); }
                                        );
                                    },
                                    function(error) {
                                        console.log("Error creating answer: ", error);
                                        console.log(peer);
                                    });
                            }
                        },
                        function(error) {
                            console.log("setRemoteDescription error: ", error);
                        }
                    );
                    console.log("Description Object: ", desc);

                });

                /**
                 * The offerer will send a number of ICE Candidate blobs to the answerer so they 
                 * can begin trying to find the best path to one another on the net.
                 */
                signaling_socket.on('iceCandidate', function(config) {
                    var peer = peers[config.peer_id];
                    var ice_candidate = config.ice_candidate;
                    peer.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(ice_candidate));
                });


                /**
                 * When a user leaves a channel (or is disconnected from the
                 * signaling server) everyone will recieve a 'removePeer' message
                 * telling them to trash the media channels they have open for those
                 * that peer. If it was this client that left a channel, they'll also
                 * receive the removePeers. If this client was disconnected, they
                 * wont receive removePeers, but rather the
                 * signaling_socket.on('disconnect') code will kick in and tear down
                 * all the peer sessions.
                 */
                signaling_socket.on('removePeer', function(config) {
                    console.log('Signaling server said to remove peer:', config);
                    var peer_id = config.peer_id;
                    if (peer_id in peer_media_elements) {
                        peer_media_elements[peer_id].remove();
                    }
                    if (peer_id in peers) {
                        peers[peer_id].close();
                    }

                    delete peers[peer_id];
                    delete peer_media_elements[config.peer_id];
                });
            }




            /***********************/
            /** Local media stuff **/
            /***********************/
            function setup_local_media(callback, errorback) {
                if (local_media_stream != null) {  /* ie, if we've already been initialized */
                    if (callback) callback();
                    return; 
                }
                /* Ask user for permission to use the computers microphone and/or camera, 
                 * attach it to an <audio> or <video> tag if they give us access. */
                console.log("Requesting access to local audio / video inputs");


                navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);

                attachMediaStream = function(element, stream) {
                    console.log('DEPRECATED, attachMediaStream will soon be removed.');
                    element.srcObject = stream;
                 };

                navigator.getUserMedia({"audio":USE_AUDIO, "video":USE_VIDEO},
                    function(stream) { /* user accepted access to a/v */
                        console.log("Access granted to audio/video");
                        local_media_stream = stream;
                        var local_media = USE_VIDEO ? $("<video>") : $("<audio>");
                        local_media.attr("autoplay", "autoplay");
                        local_media.attr("muted", "true"); /* always mute ourselves by default */
                        local_media.attr("controls", "");
                        $('body').append(local_media);
                        attachMediaStream(local_media[0], stream);

                        if (callback) callback();
                    },
                    function() { /* user denied access to a/v */
                        console.log("Access denied for audio/video");
                        alert("You chose not to provide access to the camera/microphone, demo will not work.");
                        if (errorback) errorback();
                    });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='init()'>
        <!-- 
        the <video> and <audio> tags are all added and removed dynamically
        in 'onAddStream', 'setup_local_media', and 'removePeer'/'disconnect'
        -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`navigator.getUserMedia` is only available in secure contexts (i.e. https or localhost) - is your server running on https?

Note that `navigator.getUserMedia` is deprecated, you should be using the promise-based `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` - Safari only supports the latter.